# Transpose list with numbers and text

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

can't figure out how to do this:

```
list = {i=0,i=1,i=2,i=3,i=4,i=5}
```

It's trivial but I don't get it. I was trying to did this with MapThread and such but with no result.

So now I have something like this:

```
numbers = Table[x, {x, 0, 5}]
text = Table["i=", 6]
```

Then

```
Transpose[text, numbers]
```

give me this:

```
Transpose::perm1: Entry {0,1,2,3,4,5} in permutation {{0,1,2,3,4,5}} is not a positive machine integer.
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Table["i="<>ToString[i],{i,0,6}]` ?  Untested, no MMA on this machine.

Comment: It worked! I like to do this in my way if possible, but appreciate your answer!

Comment: `MapThread[Row@{##} &, {text, numbers}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used wrong syntax for `Transpose`. The correct version:

```
Row /@ Transpose[{text, numbers}]
```

> ```
> {i=0, i=1, i=2, i=3, i=4, i=5}
> ```

Comment: thanks, can you please also show full version without this "/@" alternative form of Map?

Comment: You mean `Map[Row, Transpose[{text, numbers}]]`? You could find this yourself by evaluating `Row /@ Transpose[{text, numbers}] // Hold // FullForm`.